# plot data with different scale on same y axis on subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe with variable scale data, I am trying to get a plot with subplots. something like this.[image]

```
raw_data = {'strike_date': ['2019-10-31', '2019-11-31','2019-12-31','2020-01-31', '2020-02-31'], 
            'strike': [100.00, 113.00, 125.00, 126.00, 135.00], 
            'lastPrice': [42, 32, 36, 18, 23], 
            'volume': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
            'openInterest': [166, 0, 0, 62, 12]}
    ploty_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['strike_date', 'strike', 'lastPrice', 'volume', 'openInterest'])
    ploty_df





strike_date strike  lastPrice   volume  openInterest
0   2019-10-31  100.0   42  4   166
1   2019-11-31  113.0   32  24  0
2   2019-12-31  125.0   36  31  0
3   2020-01-31  126.0   18  2   62
4   2020-02-31  135.0   23  3   12
```

this is what I tried so far with a twinx, if you noticed the out put is a flat data without any scale difference for strike and volume.

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

mm = ax.twinx()
yy = ax.twinx()
for col in ploty_df.columns:
        mm.plot(ploty_df.index,ploty_df[[col]],label=col)
mm.set_ylabel('volume')
yy.set_ylabel('strike')
yy.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
yy.set_ylim(mm.get_ylim()[0]*12, mm.get_ylim()[1]*12)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)

handles, labels = mm.get_legend_handles_labels()
mm.legend(fontsize=14, loc=6)
plt.show()
```

and the output

[image]

Comment: Do you want to plot `strike`, `lastPrice`, `volume` and `openInterest` against `strike_date`? How many different y-axis do you want to use?

Comment: a couple of quick comments on your code: if you only want a secondary y-axis you don't need to call `twinx()` twice, moreover with your actual code you are plotting all the columns on the same axes (the one that you defined as `mm`) without using your main axes, `ax`.

Comment: @baccandr, yes, I want strike,lastPrice,volume and oPenInterest against strike _date, If you look at the example image I provided, it is doing openInterest, price and some aggregate of them in the chart. I guess mm is the main axis here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem with your script is that you are generating 3 axes but only plotting on one of them, you need to think of each axes as a separate object with its own y-scale, y-limit and so. So for example in your script when you call `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` you generate the first axes that you call ax (this is the standard yaxis with the scale on the left-side of your plot). If you want to plot something on this axes you should call `ax.plot()` but in your case you are plotting everything on the axes that you called mm.
I think you should really go through the matplotlib documentation do understand these concepts better. For plotting on multiple y-axis I would recommend you to have a look at this [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html).

Below you can find a basic example to plot your data on 3 different y-axis, you can take it as a starting point to produce the graph you are looking for.

```
#convert the index of your dataframe to datetime
plot_df.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(plot_df.strike_date)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

l1,=ax.plot(plot_df['strike'],'r')
ax.set_ylabel('Stike')

ax2=ax.twinx()
l2,=ax2.plot(plot_df['lastPrice'],'g')
ax2.set_ylabel('lastPrice')

ax3=ax.twinx()
l3,=ax3.plot(plot_df['volume'],'b')
ax3.set_ylabel('volume')
ax3.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
ax3.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

ax.legend((l1,l2,l3),('Stike','lastPrice','volume'),loc='center left')
```

here the result:
[image]

**p.s.** Your example dataframe contains non existing dates (31st February 2020) so you have to modify those in order to be able to convert the index to datetime.